# I can't find user by id all my valors is empty in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp

hello i need find user by id for my reports this is my code.
Now in this part of my code.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('soya existencia', array('controller' => 'Reportesoyaexistencias', 'action' => 'export_xls', $soyareporte['Soyareporte']['id'])); ?>
```

I set the id of user because just a need the report of this user.In my index just I do a link,this link set my id to reporteexistenciassoya where i need that just show me the id sent and  all records . this is all code:

SoyareportesController.php

index.ctp

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('username', 'Nombre de Usuario');?> </th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('nombre', 'Nombre (s)');?> </th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('apellido', 'Apellido (s)');?> </th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('email', 'Email');?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Grupo.categoria', 'Categoria');?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Grupo.subcategoria', 'Sub-Categoria');?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Perfil.codigogeneral', 'Codigo General');?></th>
                <th>Soya report</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
        <?php $count=0; ?>
        <?php foreach ($soyareportes as $soyareporte): ?>
        <?php $count ++;?>
        <?php if($count % 2): echo '<tr>'; else: echo '<tr class="zebra">' ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $soyareporte['Soyareporte']['username']; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $soyareporte['Soyareporte']['nombre']; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $soyareporte['Soyareporte']['apellido']; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $soyareporte['Soyareporte']['email']; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $soyareporte['Grupo']['categoria']; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $soyareporte['Grupo']['subcategoria']; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $soyareporte['Perfil']['codigogeneral']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->Html->link('soya existencia', array('controller' => 'Reportesoyaexistencias', 'action' => 'export_xls', $soyareporte['Soyareporte']['id'])); ?>
</td>
        </tr>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php unset($soyarreporte); ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Now in this part of my code. I receipt values the id but when I want to display the valors, but all values ​​are empty.

Reportesoyaexistencias.php

```
<?php
class ReportesoyaexistenciasController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Reportesoyaexistencias';
    function export_xls($id = null) {
        $this->loadModel("Reportesoyaexistencia");
        //$this->Reportesoyaexistencia->recursive = 1;

        $data = $this->Reportesoyaexistencia->findById($id);

        if (!$this->request->data) {
                $this->request->data = $data;
        }

        $this->set('soyaexistencias',$data);

        //$this->render('export_xls','export_xls');
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show relationship between `Reportesoyaexistencia` and `Soyareporte`?

Comment: wat see in your view if you add debug($data); after $data = $this->Reportesoyaexistencia->findById($id);